# Python OR-Tools Distance between points

Tags: python, or-tools

I am using the or-tools constraint solver to find working positions of items in a room. I am using the CP solver instead of the knapsack solver because I need to add additional constraints.

I am representing each item as an x interval and y interval and adding a constraint like this:

`model.AddNoOverlap2D(x_intervals, y_intervals)`

This helps to place the objects such that they do not overlap, but I need to add another constraint to ensure there is some distance between the objects. This should be a basic 2D distance between the objects, but this formula requires sqrt and pow functions which do not seem usable by IntVar items.

I have considered using another "spacer object" that is centered on each primary object, and adding another `NoOverlap2D` constraint, but this would result in blocking out an entire square of space when the distance formula would be a more precise distance that doesn't waste as much space in the room.

**Edit** - The code below is now working for putting a distance constraint on items.

After the suggestion from Laurent I have tried to make many intermediate variables to handle this, but am stuck on multiplying or dividing the IntVars defining the intervals of the shape locations:

```
# Now lets make all possible combinations and make a distance between them
combos = list(combinations(range(len(rects_data)), 2))

print(combos) 

currentDistanceId = 0

distanceVariables = []

for listSet in combos:
    leftItem = all_vars[listSet[0]]
    rightItem = all_vars[listSet[1]]

    if leftItem.holderType == HolderType.Person and rightItem.holderType == HolderType.Person:
        print(f"Adding distances between {listSet[0]} and {listSet[1]} because both are people")
        
        currentDistanceId = currentDistanceId + 1

        # Add an intermediate variable to store the sum of x for the center of left object
        leftCenterXSum = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x*2, f"leftCenterXSum{currentDistanceId}")
        # Add constraint to it
        model.Add(leftCenterXSum == leftItem.x2 + leftItem.x1)
        # Add an intermediate variable to store the center of x of the left object
        leftCenterX = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x, f"leftCenterX{currentDistanceId}")
        # Add a constraint to divide it by 2 to make it te center
        model.AddDivisionEquality(leftCenterX, leftCenterXSum, 2)

        ## Repeat for x and y for left and right objects
        leftCenterYSum = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.y*2, f"leftCenterYSum{currentDistanceId}")
        model.Add(leftCenterYSum == leftItem.y2 + leftItem.y1)
        leftCenterY = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.y, f"leftCenterY{currentDistanceId}")
        model.AddDivisionEquality(leftCenterY, leftCenterYSum, 2)

        rightCenterXSum = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x*2, f"rightCenterXSum{currentDistanceId}")
        model.Add(rightCenterXSum == rightItem.x2 + rightItem.x1)
        rightCenterX = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x, f"rightCenterX{currentDistanceId}")
        model.AddDivisionEquality(rightCenterX, rightCenterXSum, 2)

        rightCenterYSum = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.y*2, f"rightCenterYSum{currentDistanceId}")
        model.Add(rightCenterYSum == rightItem.y2 + rightItem.y1)
        rightCenterY = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.y, f"rightCenterY{currentDistanceId}")
        model.AddDivisionEquality(rightCenterY, rightCenterYSum, 2)

        # Create variable for difference of x
        xDiff = model.NewIntVar(-horizon.x, horizon.x, f"xDiff{currentDistanceId}")

        # Create constraint for difference of x
        model.Add(xDiff == rightCenterX - leftCenterX)

        # Create variable for difference of y
        yDiff = model.NewIntVar(-horizon.y, horizon.y, f"yDiff{currentDistanceId}")

        # Create constraint for difference for y
        model.Add(yDiff == rightCenterY - leftCenterY)

        # Create variables for x and y squared
        xDiffSquared = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x**2, f"xDiffSquared{currentDistanceId}")
        yDiffSquared = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.y**2, f"yDiffSquared{currentDistanceId}")

        # Add constraint to multiply them
        model.AddMultiplicationEquality(xDiffSquared, [xDiff, xDiff])
        model.AddMultiplicationEquality(yDiffSquared, [yDiff, yDiff])

        totalDistance = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon.x**2 + horizon.y**2, f"totalDistance{currentDistanceId}")

        model.Add(totalDistance == xDiffSquared + yDiffSquared)

        distanceVariables.append(totalDistance)

        model.Add( totalDistance >= distanceSquared )
    else:
        print(f"Skipping distances between {listSet[0]} and {listSet[1]} because one is furniture")
```

Comment: Can you add the problem variables / objective as you have it now, and describe in words the extra constraint you want to add?

Comment: Added pseudo code in my answer.

Comment: @LaurentPerron - thanks. I think I got there as well and have updated my code. It's at least compiling now, but it doesn't find a solution for 2 objects in a space when they should definitely have enough room for the distance. I'm going through and double checking now.

Comment: pow is ** instead of ^

Comment: @Stradivari - thank you! This seems to get me a bit closer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) >= d
```

Why don't you write

```
(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 >= d^2
```

Which is supported. You will need to write (in pseudo code)

```
IntVar t_x
Add(t_x == x1 - x2)
IntVar t_sx
AddMultiplicationEquality(t_sx, [t_x, t_x])

IntVar t_y
Add(t_y == y1 - y2)
IntVar t_sy
AddMultiplicationEquality(t_sy, [t_y, t_y])

Add(t_sx + t_sy >= d * d)
```

Comment: Beautiful... I never thought to square the target to get around the sqrt issue. I've updated my question with my attempt to do the `many intermediate variables` can you further advise how to resolve it? Dividing or multiplying two IntVars.